# Regex to strip image dimentions 125x125

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a directory in which I store images the directory is ALWAYS `125x125` or `468x60` or various different sizes of width before the x and various heights after the x

I have a constant

> x

```
imgheight = imgdimentions.replace(/(.*?)x/ig, '');
```

if I use the above regex I can get the image height.

How can I get the image width - The part before the X

```
imgwidth = imgdimentions.replace(/x(.*?)/ig, '');
```

I have tried the above but it gives me a error

Thanks

Comment: "ALWAYS 125x125 or 468x60 or various different sizes"?

Comment: What I mean is that the constant is always x - and the image width is always before the x and the image height is always behind the x - Also why have you edited the question to remove the classic asp. In the past I had various people asking me if it is coded in php or in asp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var img_dimensions = imgdimentions.split("x");
var img_width      = img_dimensions[0];
var img_height     = img_dimensions[1];
```

What you meant to do was

```
var imgheight = imgdimentions.replace(/.*x/, '');
var imgwidth  = imgdimentions.replace(/x.*/, '');
```

but that's needlessly complicated in comparison to just using `split()`. Note that neither the `.*?` reluctant quantifier nor the parentheses nor the `ig` modifiers are actually necessary for the regexes here.

Comment: +1 for almost mind reading - I was sure he wanted to remove `<img>` tags.

Comment: Perfect Thank you very much Tomalak - I did not even think about the split function - I really appreciate your feedback!

Comment: @GeraldFerreira: You're welcome. I know it's tempting to use regex for everything, but many tasks can be solved easier with more appropriate tools. As a side effect, it's easier to understand what `split()` does  when reading/maintaining the code.